# Weather forecast: Direct Link for info in specified location on specified time

Tags: web-applications, calendar, weather

I have a calendar web application. In the event detail view I would like to include a link to a weather site, which displays the weather for the event location and the event time.

Something like this: `http://freeweatherinfosite.org/show-weather?location=Berlin&date=2011-06-23&time=1100GMT`

A link for an iframe or a "widget" with this information would be nice, too.

I am not looking for an API.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this weather.com feature](http://www.weather.com/services/oap/weather-widgets.html)

It asks you a few questions and then generates the widget code for you

**Update**:
[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-sites-to-download-weather-widgets-for-your-blog-or-website/) are 5 more alternatives

Comment: Thank you, but it does not ask for a date and doesn't recognize smaller european cities.

Comment: I added 5 more possible alternatives, check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you again, but all of these show the current weather and do not allow to specify a date. Probably I am the only one, who wants a weather forecast for events in his calendar. :-(

Comment: You could put the weather widget together with a date widget inside the same container, in a way that looks like they are the same widget

Comment: It is not the case to show the date. I need to specify it so that the widget shows weather for the specified date instead of for "now". Example: When I open my calendar, then click into tomorrows event "outdoor party in Hannover, Germany", I would like to see the weather for tomorrow in Hannover, Germany there. Not the weather for now in a fixed place.

Comment: Understood... I think you should write your own widget then